# The name `addtaghelper` does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

## Question

I'm trying to use ASP.NET 5 Tag Helpers. Having configured server-side error messages, I'm receiving the following:

> error CS0103: The name 'addtaghelper' does not exist in the current context

From reading online tutorials, `addtaghelper` is *supposed* to exist. In `project.json` we've added this:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4"
```

Also, in `_ViewStart.cs` we have the following:

```
@addtaghelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Why does `addtaghelper` not exist in the current context? How can we add it to the current context?

I've tried camel casing as `@addTagHelper` but this leads to a new error:

> Invalid tag helper directive look up text 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'. The correct look up text format is: "typeName, assemblyName".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/TagHelperSample.Web/Views/_GlobalImport.cshtml). This is the directive to add.

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Gotchas:

- Quotes are optional [(see conversation on GitHub)](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1200).
- The directive is case sensitive and requires camel casing.
- To include all tag helpers, we use `*` for the `typeName`.
- As of today, `project.json` must have `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4"` in the `dependencies` section.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro#managing-tag-helper-scope

Comment: It appears both work, interesting, guess I jumped the gun.  Sorry, Edit the answer and I'll remove the downvote. VS defaults to no quotes so I thought they changed it. (I was also having issues and I thought it was because of the quotes, but ended up it wasn't) [it was removed at one point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413432/addtaghelper-could-not-load-file-or-assembly]