# @addTagHelper could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET core project generated with Yeoman generator-aspnet.
My problem is that I can't use the generator provided tag helper (and my test tag help doesn't work either).
The project name is `react_tests`, and this is the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file

```
@using react_tests
@using react_tests.Models
@using react_tests.Models.AccountViewModels
@using react_tests.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, react_tests
```

I tried replacing the last line with:

```
@addTagHelper "*, react_tests"
```

and

```
@addTagHelper "*, TagHelpers"//the folder for tag helpers
```

and

```
@addTagHelper "react_tests.TagHelpers.MenuLinkTagHelper, react_tests"
```

But I always receive the following error:

> Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'react_tests'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'react_tests, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: your project may be named 'react_tests', but is that the assembly name it generates?

Answer (score 0):

For others gettings this error, it occurs if the name given is not an assembly name. In my case, I put in a namespace by mistake.

It has nothing to do with quotes either (official response: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1200).

Answer (score -2):

Drop the quotation marks in the @addTagHelper directive.

Comment: I don't think the quotation marks matter. I use them in my projects and they work fine.

Comment: Sorry. They did in a pre-RTM release.